# Correct vertex normals on a heightmapped geodesic sphere

Tags: c++, opengl

Have generated a geodesic sphere, and am using perlin noise to generate hills etc. Will be looking into using the tessalation shader to divide further. However, I'm using normal mapping, and to do this I am generating tangents and bitangents in the following code:

```
//Calulate the tangents
deltaPos1 = v1 - v0;
deltaPos2 = v2 - v0;

deltaUV1 = t1 - t0;
deltaUV2 = t2 - t0;

float r = 1.0f / (deltaUV1.x * deltaUV2.y - deltaUV1.y * deltaUV2.x);
tangent = (deltaPos1 * deltaUV2.y - deltaPos2 * deltaUV1.y) * r;
bitangent = (deltaPos2 * deltaUV1.x - deltaPos1 * deltaUV2.x) * r;
```

Before I was using height mapping, the normals on a sphere are simple.

```
normal = normalize(point-origin);
```

But obviously this is very different once you involve a height map. I'm currently crossing the tangent and bitangent in the shader to figure out the normal, but this is produces some weird results

```
    mat3 normalMat = transpose(inverse(mat3(transform)));

//vec3 T = normalize(vec3(transform*tangent));
vec3 T = normalize(vec3(normalMat * tangent.xyz));

vec3 B = normalize(vec3(normalMat * bitangent.xyz));

vec3 N = normalize(cross(T, B));

//old normal line here
//vec3 N = normalize(vec3(normalMat * vec4(normal, 0.0).xyz));

TBN = mat3(T, B, N);


outputVertex.TBN = TBN;
```

However this produces results looking like this:

[image: Weird results]

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Edit-
Have reverted back to not doing any height mapping. This is simply the earth projected onto a geodesic sphere, with a specular and normal map. You can see I'm getting weird lighting across all of the triangles, especially where the angle of the light is  steeper (so naturally the tile would be darker). I should note that I'm not indexing the triangles at all at the moment, I've read somewhere that my tangents and bitangents should be averages of all the similar points, not quite understanding what this would achieve or how to do that. Is that something I need to be looking into? 
I have also reverted to using the original normals `normalize(point-origin)` for this example too, meaning my TBN matrix calcs look like

```
mat3 normalMat = transpose(inverse(mat3(transform)));

vec3 T = normalize(vec3(transform * tangent));

vec3 B = normalize(vec3(transform * bitangent));

vec3 N = normalize(vec3(normalMat * vec4(normal, 0.0).xyz));

TBN = mat3(T, B, N);

outputVertex.TBN = TBN;
```

The cube is just my "player", I use it just to help with lighting etc and seeing where the camera is. Also note that removing the normal mapping completely and just using the input normals fixes the lighting.
[image]

Thanks guys.

Comment: @WillHain Read about [Gram–Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)

Comment: Why don’t you just cross `deltaPos1` and `deltaPos2`?  They should span the same subspace as the tangents by definition.

Comment: @DavisHerring that would give the correct normal would it? Thanks

Comment: A few things: 1) Your calculation of tangents and bitangents are correct for linear maps (e.g. inside a triangle). How are you using it to derive per-vertex vectors? 2) For normal-mapping, you don't want an orthogonal tangent frame unless your parametrization is orthogonal. So don't orthogonalize. 3) You should not transform tangent and bitangent with the inverse-transpose, but simply with `transform` --- In the end, none of this is a real reason why it should break so dramatically. Try to visualize the vectors and see what is going on.

Comment: Ah, and 4) calculating the normal from the tangent and bitangent is perfectly valid.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: isn't it the case, that tangent space normal maps are calculated with orthonormal transforms in mind?

Comment: @NicoSchertler the above is everything I'm doing to the tangents and bitangents for normal mapping. What would I need to do to make it work across a mesh? Also I don't quite understand "you don't want an orthogonal tangent frame unless your parametrization is orthogonal". What is my parametrization? And also just to check, my current normal calculations are correct without orthogonalizing? Thanks

Comment: Have updated the question as simplifying the problem has proven that I'm doing something more fundamentally wrong here. Thanks guys

Comment: @NicoSchertler: "calculating the normal from the tangent and bitangent is perfectly valid.". I would not do that. I'd calculate normal as usual (weighting face normals, or by some other means), calculate tangent&bitangent, and I'd refine tangent&bitangent, so the whole normal/tangent/bitangent system is perpendicular. Then, it is a good idea, to calculate normal from tangent&bitangent (because we will get a good normal).

Comment: @Will If you calculate all vectors per triangle, then it is natural that you see their borders (because lighting changes abruptly). 1) You have two options: Simply average them over the faces incident to a vertex like geza suggested 2) Solve a least-squares system to find them. -- But in neither case you should get such severe artifacts. Try to gradually remove things to see what causes the problems. Also try visualizing the vectors as little lines.

Comment: @geza Usually parametrizations (i.e. the uv map) are set up to be angle-preserving (i.e., orthogonal). But sometimes it is just not possible. And if you have a non-orthogonal tangent frame, it is not clear how to derive an orthogonal one (Gram-Schmidt will somewhat arbitrarily correct one of the tangents). For normal calculation from tangent/bitangent it does not matter if they are orthogonal. As long as you normalize and they are in the correct tangent plane, you get the same normal direction.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: I don't think that uv maps are set up to be angle-preserving in practice. At least, I've never heard a gfx artist to use such uv maps. They just uv it, minimizing distortion. But not because of tangent space. It think it is impossible to have such an uv map, which generates perp. tangents for almost all meshes. So an orthogonalization is must. GS is not the best, but usually works well.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: but sure, for OP's screenshot, there is a more serious bug, it's not just the absence of orthogonalization. This is what I said in my first comment.

Comment: @geza This is getting a bit off-topic, so this is going to be my last comment about this: Angle preservation is usually part of the distortion you minimize but perfect angle preservation is rarely achievable, indeed (at least if you also want to preserve area). The maps cannot really account for that non-orthogonality (imagine a skinned model, where the skew changes). All the normal maps say is "red=tangent dir, green=bitangent dir, blue=normal dir". And if tangent and bitangent are non-orthogonal, so be it. The normal will adapt accordingly.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: I'm just commenting on your 2) point. In my opinion, that's not true. Normal maps (the texture itself) should be interpreted in an orthonormal system. We should aim for this. Especially, if we can (static mesh, at precalc). "The normal will adapt accordingly" is kinda true, but it will have bad artifacts. In my opinion (again), normal should be calculated as usual. Then the tangent, bitangent & normal system should be orthogonalized. It's a bad way to calculate normal as cross(tangent, bitangent).

Comment: I've now averaged my tangents and bitangents across the mesh - every common point's tangents and bitangents are being added together, then in the vertex shader they are normalized, before being used to calculate the normal. Same effect still present

Comment: @WillHain: I don't think that's a good idea to derive normal from tangents. It may work, I don't know. When I implemented normal mapping, I didn't do this. I calculated normals as usual. Then I calculated tangents. Then I orthogonalized this system. And now, you can calculate any of these vectors from the other two. But calculating normals from tangents seems a bad idea. It won't be a quality normal vector. Normals should be derived from face normals, weighted by face area or angle (in case of smooth surfaces).

Comment: @WillHain: if this still doesn't work, then you should visualize normal&tangent vectors in the render, and start with a small (few vertices) mesh, where the bug happens. This way you can find out what's the problem.

Comment: Okay, how do I calculate them "as usual"? I've only ever used them from a tool like assimp or crossing the tangent and bitangent

Comment: Please put @<username> into your comment, so I get notified. The usual way to do this is to average faces normal (faces which touch a vertex). Averaging should be weighted. Two usual approaches to use weight as the area of the face, or the angle of the egdes at the vertex. This averaging should be done only, if the surface is smooth. For example, for a cube, you'll have 3 vertex normals at a vertex (each for the three faces touching a vertex). In this case, vertex normal is just the face normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (second) problem was indeed fixed by indexing out all my points, and averaging the results of the tangents and bitangents. This led to the fixing of the first problem, which was indirectly caused by the bad tangents and bitangents.